# How to reach php $_SESSION array in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to build some javascript function and I need to check if the users are logged in or not. When a user log in to my site I set a variable in session array named is_logged. I want to reach that variable in javascript is it possible???
I tried some ways but did not work like following:

```
var session = "<?php print_r $_SESSION['is_logged']; ?>";
alert(session);
```

and:

```
var session = '<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['is_logged']) ?>';
alert(session);
```

It is either show a text or never alert at all

Comment: Is that a js file or php file where you are alerting the value..??

Comment: How about setting a cookie instead and have the javascript check the cookie?

Comment: it is a js file where I alert the value

Comment: is it better with cookies??

Comment: I hope the value of this variable doesn't determine access to personal or sensitive information because it's trivial to open the console and start manipulating it. All the logic about whether someone is logged in or not should be performed on the server side where it can't (easily) be tampered with.

Comment: echo is the same just showing a text not the value of the variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reach all elements of $_SESSION in JavaScript you may use json_encode,

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["x"]="y";
?>

<script>
 var session = eval('(<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION)?>)');
 console.log(session);

//you may access session variable "x" as follows
alert(session.x);
</script>
```

But note that, exporting all $_SESSION variable to client is not safe at all.

Comment: I am working on js file and want to show a php variable not the reverse,I use your code but it shows me a syntax error

Comment: You cannot test my code fragment on js file, since they bypass php execution. Paste export section in index.php or what ever script you use to load js files, then use session.x to refer the session variables.

Comment: for now I used your code in my index file I hope it will work fine. thank you

Comment: Why would you use `eval` if you already have a JSON-encoded string? `const session = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION) ?>;` is all you need.

Answer (score 6):

Just echo it:

```
var session = <?php echo $_SESSION['is_logged']?'true':'false'; ?>;
alert(session);
```

You need tertiary operator, as `false` is echoed as empty string so it would lead to `var session = ;` which is a JS syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

In a js file you cant get the value of a php variable or php code doesnt works on a js file because php code will works in a .php extension file.
So one method is to set the session  value as a hidden element value and in your js file get the value of the hidden element.

In the html:

```
<input type="hidden" id="sess_var" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['is_logged']; ?>"/>
```

In your js:

```
var session = document.getElementById('sess_var').value;
alert(session);
```

Comment: it is just alert the session as text not giving the value of the variable

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
var session = "<?php echo $_SESSION['is_logged'] ?>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do things like this

Just insert the `$_SESSION['is_logged']` in a hidden field like

```
<input type = "hidden" value = "<?php echo $_SESSION['is_logged']; ?>" id = "is_logged" />
```

Then you can access that in your jquery like this

```
var is_logged = jQuery.trim($('#is_logged').val());
//then do validation here
```

Comment: Awful way. jQuery is 100% useless here.

Comment: 1) "is_logged" is a boolean, no trim needed, 
2) `document.getElementById("is_logged").value` is by far faster (http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-jquery-id/13).

Answer (score -5):

```
   var get_session=<?php echo $_SESSION['is_login'] 

  alert(get_session);
    ?>
```

## **Just try this ** ##